# Optimisation ideas - Longest common substring

Tags: c++, optimization, longest-substring

I have this program which is supposed to find the Longest Common Substring of a number of strings. Which it does, but if the strings are very long (i.e. >8000 characters long), it works slowly (1.5 seconds).
Is there any way to optimise that?

The program is this:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>


using namespace std;

const unsigned short MAX_STRINGS = 10;
const unsigned int  MAX_SIZE=10000;
vector<string> strings;
unsigned int len;

string GetLongestCommonSubstring( string string1, string string2 );
inline void readNumberSubstrings();
inline const string getMaxSubstring();

void readNumberSubstrings()
{
    cin >> len;

    assert(len > 1 && len <=MAX_STRINGS);

    strings.resize(len);

    for(register unsigned int i=0; i<len;i++)
        strings[i]=string(MAX_SIZE,0);

    for(register unsigned int i=0; i<len; i++)
        cin>>strings[i];
}

 const string getMaxSubstring()
{
    string maxSubstring=strings[0];
    for(register unsigned int i=1; i < len; i++)
        maxSubstring=GetLongestCommonSubstring(maxSubstring, strings[i]);
    return maxSubstring;
}

string GetLongestCommonSubstring( string string1, string string2 ) 
{

    const int solution_size = string2.length()+ 1;

    int *x=new int[solution_size]();
    int *y= new int[solution_size]();

    int **previous = &x;
    int **current = &y;

    int max_length = 0;
    int result_index = 0;

    int j;
    int length;
    int M=string2.length() - 1;

    for(register int i = string1.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(register int j = M; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            if(string1[i] != string2[j]) 
                (*current)[j] = 0;
            else 
            {
                length = 1 + (*previous)[j + 1];
                if (length > max_length)
                {
                    max_length = length;
                    result_index = i;
                }

                (*current)[j] = length;
            }
        }

        swap(previous, current);
    }
    string1[max_length+result_index]='\0';
    return &(string1[result_index]);
}

int main()
{
    readNumberSubstrings();
    cout << getMaxSubstring() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*Note*: there is a reason why I didn't write code that would solve this problem with suffix trees (they're large).

Comment: What about parallelization? You could easily use OpenMP for that. The only problem is that you have to crawl the table diagonally.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input?

Comment: The thought has occurred, but I'd like to optimize what I have first.

Comment: Well, if I try it in a comment, it will be more than 9000 characters "too long".

Comment: `register` is pointless with modern compilers and you don't need double indirection for `previous` and `current`. It probably won't help much with performance though.

Comment: @Chiffa a small input sample suffices. But without it, I can't even execute your code..

Comment: Perhaps, but for the moment I can't think of anything much better.

Comment: Well, for example I input 10 random strings like this:   10
mrqmbmdztpposfyjawqnsgghziumfuwekudgvtwbmpvp
qwikbdlefitrmbmdztpposfyjawqncjgvwqyurt
kjehpbvoodpdwionigwjbczmddlomvmbmdztpposfyjawqnio
hyhpqeambmdztpposfyjawqn
tiewwnhvdtloibzmrgsywmbmdztpposfyjawqndcupawrytbakvayvc
vbqqyorqepgzcggfkviyerjmbmdztpposfyjawqnb
ysdxhmbmdztpposfyjawqnbopejbwokcnjabwrjxc
mbmdztpposfyjawqn
huznybnvcuzfqmbmdztpposfyjawqnofkonyskbsig
xgokylmbmdztpposfyjawqnuqlfzreibpdcaevptrpxxdvv

Comment: Anyway, its a longest common substring problem; sample inputs are easy to come up with. Just input something like 3 sample1 sample2 samplesample3

Comment: @Chiffa Almost flagged your comment when I got here ; D

Comment: Won't make much of a difference, but you should pass the arguments to `GetLongestCommonSubstring` as `const string&` and not `string`. In C++ we pass objects by reference to avoid copying.

Comment: Oh. Haven't thought of that; thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Often when it comes to optimization, a different approach might be your only true option rather than trying to incrementally improve the current implementation. Here's my idea:

- create a list of *valid characters* that might appear in the longest common substring. I.e., if a character doesn't appear in all strings, it can't be part of the longest common substring.
- separate each string into multiple strings containing only valid characters
- for every such string, create every possible substring and add it to the list as well
- filter (as with the characters) all strings, that don't show up in all lists.

The complexity of this obviously depends largely on the number of invalid characters. if it's zero, this approach doesn't help at all.

Some remarks on your code: Don't try to be overly clever. The compiler will optimize so much, there's really no need for you to put `register` in your code. Second, your allocating strings and then overwrite them (in `readNumberSubstrings`), that's totally unnecessary. Third, pass by const reference if you can. Fourth, don't use raw pointers, especially if you never `delete []` your `new []`d objects. Use `std::vector`s instead, it behaves well with exceptions (which you might encounter, you're using strings a lot!).

Comment: Thanks) Well, I just happen to like 'register'. And yes, I see how re-writing my code could solve my problems, but I'll try your advices first.

Comment: I've modified my function which used to overwrite strings and am now passing `string&`s instead of `string`s, and I'm measuring the time it takes for the code to work using `std::chrono` but, unless I'm measuring something really wrong, it's still slow.

Comment: To be more precise, it takes about 3 seconds to compare 2 very long strings, and more than 20 for 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use suffix tree. This struct will make algorithm, which work about 1 second for 10 string with 10000 symbols.

Comment: Using a suffix tree takes a lot of memory, as far as I know.

Comment: It is, no secret there. Am I to infer that yandex expects me to use a suffix tree?

Comment: Do the developers at Yandex go around calling each other stupid and then never explaining their own code? I've only met one Yandex developer and that was what he was like.

Comment: I recommend to read "Algorithms on String, Trees, and Sequences. Computer Science and Computational Biology". The book has your problem.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't know, not being a Yandex developer. But this is straying from the coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give a Suffix Arraya try, they take as much memory as your input strings (depending on your text encoding though) and a built quickly in linear time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

Here is my JavaScript code for this

```
function LCS(as, bs, A, B) {
    var a = 0, b = 0, R = [], max = 1
    while (a < A.length && b < B.length) {
        var M = cmpAt(as, bs, A[a], B[b])
        if (M.size > 0) {
            if (M.ab < 0) {
                var x = b; while (x < B.length) {
                    var C = cmpAt(as, bs, A[a], B[x])
                    if (C.size >= M.size) {  if (C.size >= max) max = C.size, R.push([a, x, C.size]) } else break
                    x++
                }
            } else {
                var x = a; while (x < A.length) {
                    var C = cmpAt(as, bs, A[x], B[b])
                    if (C.size >= M.size) { if (C.size >= max) max = C.size, R.push([x, b, C.size]) } else break
                    x++
                }
            }
        }
        if (M.ab < 0) a++; else b++
    }
    R = R.filter(function(a){ if (a[2] == max) return true })
    return R
}

function cmpAt(a, b, x, y) {
    var c = 0
    while (true) {
        if (x == a.length) {
            if (y == b.length) return { size: c, ab: 0 }
            return { size: c, ab: -1 }
        }
        if (y == b.length) return { size: c, ab: 1 }
        if (a.charCodeAt(x) != b.charCodeAt(y)) {
            var ab = 1; 
            if (a.charCodeAt(x) < b.charCodeAt(y)) ab = -1
            return { size: c, ab: ab }
        }
        c++, x++, y++
    }
}
```